# Jquery Prepend: Cannot call method 'createDocumentFragment' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

During page startup I'm trying to add an element to the DOM.

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).prepend("<div id=new_div style=z-index:1;></div>");
});
```

I've tested this on FF21, Chrome27 and IE10. They all return the error mentioned in the title (exact wording is from the Chrome debugger).

Debugging on jquery-1.10.0.js, I tracked down the problem to line 5998 where

```
safeFrag = document.createDocumentFragment()
```

Apparently document is null. Going up the stack trace to `domManip` on line 6249 the object is passed as `this[ 0 ].ownerDocument`, which is null.

I've stripped the javascript on the page to just loading jQuery and running this command, and the issue persists.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/LWd6S/), the alert doesn't pop, meaning the javascript engine got stuck on the line before.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to prepend to document? Prepend to an actual DOM node, like document.body . Also, try using quotes for your attribute values

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to try to add an element to the start of the `document` object. It isn't an HTMLElementNode. As far as I know, you can't give it additional children at all.

If you want to add a div element to the start of something, then the highest node that is allowed to contain it is the body element, so use:

```
$(document.body).prepend
```

… instead.